# How do I prevent iWork apps from restoring windows from the previous session?

Tags: macos, iwork, resume

Whenever I reopen Pages or Numbers, all documents that I had open when I last exited are reopened. I have the "restore windows" checkbox unchecked in `System Preferences > General`, but *all* windows from my previous session are *always* reopened *every* time I re-launch Pages or Numbers. Is there a way to force iWork apps to behave as expected?

Comment: What I have done in other apps, like Firefox, is to close all windows before quitting the app.

Comment: @DaveNelson: That's not really my question.

Comment: Could you provide us with the iWork version you are running, as well as the OS X version. Also, what “Settings” are you speaking of? iWork’s? Or OS X’ System Settings?

Comment: @kopischke: Versions are all (always) current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from Apple Discussion threads (a quick search turned up [these](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16081592#16081592) [three](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15789480#15789480) [threads](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15770420#15770420) on the first page of results alone), the global Resume switch does not seem to consistently stop applications from saving and restoring Saved State information.

If you only want to disable Resume selectively for iWork, you may be best served by something like [RestoreMeNot](http://www.restoremenot.info/) or [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html), which has a dedicated tab for granularly managing Resume besides its other tweaking features.

If you want to completely disable the Resume feature, [Mac OS X Hints outlines a procedure to do so](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110918051930924). I can’t judge on it, nor recommend it, as it is altogether too hackish for my taste – the editor’s label “proceed at your own risk” applies.

Comment: So is it the case that iWork apps are among those that ignore the system-wide setting and *always* save window state (with no UI for changing that)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: looks like it, considering your difficulties. Does disabling them on a per-app basis solve the issue?